# Move Sharepoint to another server

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

Hi I have an installed SharePoint Server (all on a Single Server installed, this all is hosted on a VM) called server1.

The database was the only thing that will be hosted on a separate server.

Now my customer want's to move the system from a vm to a physical machine (with the same operating system) called server 2.
So the consequence is, that the SharePoint must move to the new system (server 2). He don't want to copy the VM onto the vm for some reason, so that is not possible.

My idea was to install the new sharepoint (on Server 2) and connect it to the existing configuration database, to which the existing sharepoint is already connected.

Then the old sharepoint (server 1) can be safely removed.

That's the plan/idea, is that possible?

If yes, does SharePoint take care about the synchronization about the iis configuration (like application pools and web applications and so on?)

If that is not possible, does it mean that i need a clean install (with creating the web applications) and migrate the existing content database into the created web applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is good. If the new server on the same domain then now issue.

- install the SharePoint on new server( make sure same patch /build level)
- Run the Config wizard on new server and join it to farm.
- if you have any manual changes in SharePoint i.e web.config, please apply on new server.
- Now update your AAM setting(if using the server name and port number)
- Update IIS bindings, and SSL certs( if ssl configured)
- If using DNS, please update them to point new server.
- Start the services on the New Server i.e User profile, MMS, Search etc
- now test everything works as expected
- time to remove the old server from farm.
- Test again.

Comment: Wonderful!!! Thx alot for this information. So the IIS settings will be applied automatically on the new server?

Comment: Sorry I missed that one...you have to update the iis bindings and also configure ssl if

Comment: Okay that's not a big deal. But the application pools and so on will be synchronized between the old and new server. A binding was very fast configured.

Comment: Yes app pools will be